# Train-Test Split with nested groups and multiple balancing factors

Tags: cross-validation, sampling, scikit-learn, caret, resampling

I have a large (~15,000) sample of data from individuals nested within families (with about half the data points sharing a family). I want to split the sample in to a training and test set so I can separate exploratory analysis from confirmation. I'm trying to replicate a paper which, rather vaguely, claimed to have split a similar sample in such a way that balance was preserved across ~7 factors with thousands of levels, while also keeping individuals from the same families together in training or test.

If there were just one balancing factor, I think I could use StratifiedGroupKFold from sklearn to do this. If there were a handful, I could interact the factors to reduce them to one stratification variable. Without the nesting issue I could use caret in R to do it. But with 7 and the nesting factor I need some other solution. Is there some way I can reduce the stratification variable and still use StratifiedGroupKFold? I've thought about trying to stratify based on some sort of propensity score but I can't figure out how to make that work.